# Regex for matching mandatory and optional characters in random order

Tags: regex, random

I need a regular expression to find Text between HTML-elements via the Visual Studion Search Engine (might by C#).

What works fine in a way is this:

```
>\s*([\w])+\s*<
```

But it has to match all the following "asdf"s:

```
<element>asdf
  <element>asdf.</element>asdf
  <element />
asdf asdf
</element>
<element>
  asdf!
</element>
```

What it should NOT find is an empty space between 2 tags, this example should match NOTHING:

```
<element>

  <element>  </element>
</element>
```

What I need in particular is a regex, that matches:

- Start with >
- End with <
- between those at least one word-characters (\w) is mandatory
- a bunch of special characters are mandatory (_ . ? , ! SPACE) are optional
- between start/end and the content there can be a unpredictable length of whitespace (means it can be a length of zero as well)
- the order of the characters between start and end is absolutly random

I don't want to get matches which includes special characters without \w.

Another, which doesn't work at all is this:

```
>\s*((?=[\w]+)(?=[ ?=()!"_]*))\s*<
```

What is the correct way to accomplish my need?

Thank you so much!

Comment: My provided input contains a . and a !. I thought that would show my purpose about these "special chars". No, i mean indeed that they are allowed, but the expression does only match if the mandatory characters show up in this area as well.

Comment: I am sorry, i made a mistake by describe the SPECIAL CHARACTERS as mandatory - i ment OPTIONAL (changed it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use one lookahead before matching the text between the `><`s:

```
>(?=[^<]*\w).*?<
```

(use "s" flag, so dot matches newline - or, use something like `[\S\s]*?` instead of `.*?`)

The lookahead ensures that there's a word character between the `>` and the `<`. Then, match and lazy-repeat any character until you get to the `<`.

https://regex101.com/r/cqinyh/2

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. And, well, tanks for...showing my how little I understand in handling regular expressions ;) Have a nice day